# Bubble sort : compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bubble-sort

I try to program some sorting, even though I don't have syntax or logic error in my code, while compiling I get an exception which seems to be related to the sorting method :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at triBulle.bulle(triBulle.java:35)
at triBulle.main(triBulle.java:64)
```

Here's my code  :

```
public static void bulle(int[] T)
{
    int n = T.length;
    boolean echange = true ;

    while((n>0) && (echange))
    {
        echange = false ;
        for(int j = 0 ; j<n ; j++)
        {
            if(T[j] >T[j+1])
            {
                int tmp = T[j];
                T[j] = T[j+1];
                T[j+1] = tmp;
                echange = true ;
            }
        }
        n = n-1;
    }

}
```

Thanks to check this out.

Comment: This isn't a compilation error as by your report the code compiles. There is however a logic error and that is why you are getting an error when you attempt to access `T[n]`

Comment: Change `for(int j = 0 ; j<n ; j++)` to `for(int j = 0 ; j<n-1 ; j++)`

Comment: "even though I don't have syntax or logic error in my code" - making that assumption is the first problem. Your first assumption whenever there's a problem is that it *is* your code that's at fault. (As is the case here...)

Comment: when youre trying to access `T[j] = T[j+1];` this line for `j=n-1` you are out of the limit of the size.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if I am wrong, but I am rather sure that, in java, an array with elements [0], [1], and [2] has a `length` of 3. So in your while-loop, if `j` is equal to `length-1` then that is the last index. Therefore, when `[j+1]` gets called, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

One way to fix it would be

```
for(int j = 1 ; j<n ; j++)
    {
        if(T[j-1] >T[j])
```

Or

```
for(int j = 0 ; j<n-1 ; j++)
    {
        if(T[j] >T[j+1])
```